# Node.js Request module returns truncated data

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, request

I'm using `request` on my `nodejs` server to call an external JSON rest service.

This is a simplified example of my code :

```
var request = require("request");

request("http://www.sitepoint.com", function(error, response, body) {
  var myJson = eval('(' + body+ ')');
});
```

It works well 90% of the time, but sometime I get this error :

```
Uncaught Syntax Error: Unexpected Token ILLEGAL
```

This error never refers to the same char into the received JSON, So in my understanding, the stream sent back by the rest service is truncated and cannot be converted to JSON.

How can I ensure myself that the request is done completly and the data complete ?

Comment: Why are you using `eval` instead of `JSON.parse`

Comment: the result will be the same, the problem is not into the parsing method, but in the content to parse

Comment: eval function execute a JS statement... its not for parsing json !

Comment: Didn't say it would be different or that it was the problem, was just asking as you could be using something specifically made to parse json instead of something that wasn't, and get a better error message possibly. And that message doesn't necessarily mean the data was truncated, it could mean the data sent back had characters in an encoding it did not understand (ie non UTF encoding).